# excel formula for 'if match on email pick up other contact info to populate adjoining cells'

Tags: excel

I am looking for an excel formula to perform the following. I have numerous tabs in a spreadsheet - 1 of which includes survey results with just the 80 contacts email addresses AI3:AI91. In a seperate tab (registrants) I have 400 emails and all the other contact details but I only need to pull out the contact info from the people who took part in the survey. Does anyone know the formula to allow excel to lookup the email address and if its present in the registrants tab look at picking up the name, phone number, company and country from the other columns and  populating the columns in the survey tab  AJ:AN ?

Comment: Match, vlookup, lookup... pick one

Comment: Thanks Amit - I've tried match and vlookup but I'm not sure of the formula ?

Comment: try this http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php

Comment: I'll give it a go - the site looks informative so fingers crossed

Comment: Its finally getting there - this site is very easy to understand - I've used the lookup example and its populated the cells with the correct info. just need to work on the N/A bit now.

Comment: Great. In the future try to generalize the problem ("excel match value and find value from adjoining cells") and you should be able to find answers on Google

Comment: Thanks again Amit - it's knowing what I want excel to do and then asking the question in the general excel language - I'll know in future.